# How to send multiple responses from an Activity

Tags: android, xamarin

I wish to start an Activity and allow it to run for a while and send multiple responses. How should I do this?

**Edit 1**: I wish to start a Xamarin Android Activity and receive back from it many responses. This means that in the called Activity I want to know how to respond without using Finish(). The doco I have found does not say how to do this.

**Edit 2**: I have two Xamarin Android Activities. [1] starts [2]. [2] wants to send many responses to [1] without finishing. All the doco I have read assumes only one response using Finish(). What am I missing?

**Edit 3** (9th Nov): The available documentation describes a simple relationship between two Activities A1 and A2: A1 creates an Intent and transmits it to A2; A2 returns (optionally) an Intent carrying information back to A1 and Finish()es.

I was asking how to transmit several (packages of information) back to A1 from A2 without A2 Finish()ing. @Gusman gave me some sample code and showed that you can do anything you like - just ignore the Android paradigm.

Here is a simplified version of what I implemented with @Gusman's help; a fairly straightforward inter-Activity telegraph system. It is not intrisically special, it is simply unexpected (to me) within the Android paradigm **as explained in the available doco**.

(Note that an Activity may be inactive (Stopped) but you can still trigger an event which runs its code.)

```
public static class ActivityMessage
    {
        public static event EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> MessageEvent;

        public static void SendMessage(string sender, string receiver,
               string messageType, Bundle bundle)
        {
            // Bundle contains optional transmitted data 
            if (bundle == null) {
                bundle = new Bundle ();
            }
            bundle.PutString ("SENDER", sender);
            bundle.PutString ("RECEIVER", receiver);
            bundle.PutString ("TYPE", messageType);
            MessageEventArgs args = new MessageEventArgs ();
            args.bundle = bundle;

            MessageEvent (sender, args);
        }
    }

// In the receiving Activity
ActivityMessage.MessageEvent += IncomingMessage;

private void IncomingMessage(object something, MessageEventArgs e)
        {
            Bundle bundle = e.bundle;
            string receiver = bundle.GetString ("RECEIVER");
            if (receiver  == "ME") {
                DoSomething(bundle);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you mean by "send multiple responses"?

Comment: What type of response you want to send. Narrow down the scope of your question

Comment: I want to return to the calling Activity more than one response without using Finish().

Comment: Explain your question more precisely otherwise your question may b closed

Comment: Would those who choose to neg my question instead please point me to the answer? If there is something I do not understand or some terminology I do not use this is not helpful.

Comment: All the documentation I can see describes an Activity being called to return a single answer. I want to return many answers.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/tour
Then come back and you'll know what to do to receive an answer probably and why this question has -2

Comment: OK thanks I read that, still not understanding why no-one is prepared to simply point me to how to return more than one response to an Activity being instantiated. I imagine I am using the wrong terminology.

Comment: If both activities are in the same Xamarin app, you can just use an static class as a bridge between then

Comment: Thanks Gusman, could you please provide more information like a code sample, or a pointer to something that I understand?

Comment: Your Question is like, "I want something to go somewhere and bring me something. Can anybody tell me how to send something to somewhere ?" How on earth one can help you when you don't tell them what exactly you want.

Comment: Can't add an answer as the question has ben put on hold...

Comment: Well that was a bad experience. Thanks for trying to help me Gusman.

Comment: Here: http://pastebin.com/neh8FZsL

Comment: Hey @MarkRoberts , you can try to fix your question, unclear questions doesn't help anyone. The scope of this site is not to ask questions and help yourself but to ask a question in a way that the question with the ansewrs with help others too.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in the third edit. Didn't realise that the question had been jailbroken.